# Extracting a particular URL from a large text file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to extract a particular URL from a large text file.

**Data (or text file):**

```
[{"profile":"164","width":638,"height":360,"mime":"video/mp4","fps":30,"url":"https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1685291596~acl=%2Fvimeo-transcode-storage-prod-us-central1-h264-360p2F3314456635875455007.mp4~hmac=938482df34b6c94756876549908053d738d426ca/vimeo-transcode-storage-prod-us-central1-h264-360p/01/2982/28/714910924/3314655007.mp4","cdn":"akamai_interconnect","quality":"360p","id":"a81ee7e1-4ae0-4b3a-85fe-7d0d8ff16b93","origin":"gcs"},{"profile":"165","width":958,"height":540,"mime":"video/mp4","fps":30,"url":"https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1685291596~acl=%2Fvimeo-transcode-storage-prod-us-west1-h264-540p%2F01%2F2982%2F28%2F714910924%2F3314655137.mp4~hmac=938482df31237894b6c947e9908053d738d4dd26ca/vimeo-transcode-storage-prod-us-west1-h264-540p/01/2982/28/714910924/3314655137.mp4","cdn":"akamai_interconnect","quality":"540p","id":"08b0edbf-ce47-4dd1-aa17-3c14ed3eccc8","origin":"gcs"},{"profile":"174","width":1278,"height":720,"mime":"video/mp4","fps":30,"url":"https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1685291596~acl=%2Fvimeo-transcode-storage-prod-us-east1-h264-720p%2F01%FFF2F2F22F3314655135.mp4~hmac=c44e0c048f008ce4996434ce5d6543234567189dbc63/vimeo-transcode-storage-prod-us-east1-h264-720p/01/2982/28/714910924/3314655135.mp4","cdn":"akamai_interconnect","quality":"720p","id":"625db5ed-2175-4977-a562-de40d84aab45","origin":"gcs"}]},"file_codecs":{"av1":[],"avc":["a81ee7e1-4ae0-4b3a-85fe-7d0d8ff16b93","d5589a0c-a69a-4428-ad7e-0c2a1e4e9f92","08b0edbf-ce47-4dd1-aa17-3c14ed3eccc8","625db5ed-2175-4977-a562-de40d84aab45"],"hevc":{"dvh1":[],"hdr":[],"sdr":[]}},"lang":"en","referrer"
```

[Here's the same text that can be viewed using an online text viewer.](https://codebeautify.org/cs/b414ce) and here's an image of the part that I am trying to extract:

[image]

**Description of the problem:**

- There are several links in the text document, including links that look similar (not same) to the one that I am trying to extract. The **only** link (from the txt file) that I need to extract contains **720p** somewhere in it.
- The URL looks like "`https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net [..] .mp4`".
- Do note, so that we don't end up getting only a subset of the desired link, that the link contains a `.mp4` once inside and once in the end. That is, it looks like "`https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net [..] .mp4~hmac= [..] .mp4`" as you should be able to see in the highlighted text in the image attached.

**The following code extracts all the urls but only partially:**

```
text_string = ""
with open("text.txt", "r") as text_file:
    text_string = text_file.read()

urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', text_string)

print(urls)
```

It prints the following: `['https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1685291596', 'https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1685291596', 'https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1685291596']`

**Modifications needed to the code:**

1. The links are not fully obtained. Only the initial part of it is obtained.
2. Not every link is needed. The desired link is described under "Description of the Problem".

Comment: As I am new to SO, your suggestions regarding modifications to the post/tags will be helpful.

Comment: Looks like a Json file. Use `json` module to parse it.

Comment: Your JSON looks broken. Is there more to it?

Comment: @InSync Yes, it's a very large text file, so I just copied a small part of it: the part around the required url.

Comment: How large is it? If it fits into your memory, better parse it as JSON and deal with it the easy way™.

Comment: And if it's too large to fit into memory all at once - look into streaming json libraries.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Not that large. Just 22-23k characters per text file, and I have close to a thousand of them. Memory won't be an issue I believe. The issue is that I don't know JSON. But I'll do a quick google search and see if I can get the work done. If not, I'll come back to SO! Thanks.

Comment: You should load the JSON, iterate over it in a way that gets you *all* the URLs, possibly use regular expressions to see which ones match the pattern, and collect those.

Comment: To summarize: JSON has six types of values: object (similar to Python's `dict`, but disallow non-string keys), array (similar to `list`), strings (delimiters must be double-quotes), numbers (`int` and `float`), booleans and `null` (`None`). Once you parsed it, it is just a normal Python value which you can iterate over.

Comment: @Grismar One last question: It's an HTML file obtained from the page source code of webpages. Can I still do it using the JSON module? As I'm getting [errors](https://i.imgur.com/U2YOY84.png) when I'm trying to parse it (assuming my way is correct), I was wondering if I'm using the correct module. Thanks again! :)

Comment: If the text you shared is a piece of JSON somewhere inside the script section of an HTML page, you could either extract the script part from the HTML, and then the JSON from that, and then follow the procedure described about - or you could apply regular expressions to the whole document, but that may complicate things if there are similar URLs outside the JSON part you are interested in. Consider looking for some clearly identifiable marker before and after the JSON section you are interested in, and extract that before passing it to `json.loads`.

Comment: Json parsing in general is a better way to parse json data but just to help you out for a pure regex solution, you can use `https:(?=[^\"]+720p)[^\"]+` regex and apply it on the text and you will get your desired matching url containing `720p` within it. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kv70Bp/1) And I can't add explanation as the question got closed.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Wow, that's very helpful (and I checked it works with the text files too). I actually get the intuition of the regex you've written but as I don't know regex, I can't reproduce it myself for other substrings. But as it looks interesting, I plan to learn it in a day or two.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

data = json.loads(json_str)
data["url"]
```

The url that you want can be retrieved by data["url"]